# How do I send the contents of a form using MAILTO without a server script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, mailto

How do I get user input from an html form and send it using a mailto link without a server script?

In the code below, I want **user_comments** to be a variable that stores the input of the form, then sends the contents of the variable by email when a user taps on the button.

If some script is necessary, please use php or javascript. Thx.

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="msg">Comments</label><br>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_comments"></textarea><br>
</form>

<button>
<a href="mailto:info@site.com?body=user_comments">Send</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't. You can't force the client to send emails for you.

Comment: Just for clearance. PHP ist Server-Side Script.
Thats still okay?

Comment: The MAILTO protocol requires user configuration of an email client for their browser. This is not something you do for them but search "how to configure browser for mailto protocol" or similar for more details. How successfully `mailto:` works afterwards still needs to be ascertained.